# How can I know if C++ compiler evaluates the expression at compile time?

Tags: c++, optimization, c++11

I have a code like this

```
const int Value = 123 * 2 + GetOffset();
```

`GetOffset` is a `constexpr` function returning `int`.

How can I make sure this expression is indeed evaluated at compile time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use `std::ratio`.  From section 20.10.1 of the C++11 standard:

> This subclause describes the ratio library. It provides a class template ratio which exactly represents any finite rational number with a numerator and denominator representable by compile-time constants of type intmax_t.

So according to the standard, this would only be valid for a compile-time constant:

```
const int value = std::ratio<123 * 2 + GetOffset()>::num;
```

So this would guarantee that the expression is evaluated at compile time.  However, it doesn't also guarantee that the expression is not evaluated at run time.

Comment: That won't make any difference; the existing initialiser is just as representable by a compile-time constant. (This will give a compile-time check that the initialiser really is a constant expression; but it seems a bit weird to abuse `ratio` for that).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I went looking through the standard for anything that mentioned "compile-time".  There weren't a lot of places, but `std::ratio` was one of them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Also note that the OP only asked if there was a way to guarantee that it was evaluated at compile-time.  They did not ask if there was a way to guarantee that it was not evaluated at run-time as well.

Comment: How does this guarantee that the expression is evaluated at compile time? It just guarantees that the expression must be recognized as a compile-time constant, not that the compiler actually evaluate it at compile time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: My interpretation of "compile-time constant" is a constant that is evaluated at compile time.  This seemed more specific than the term "constant expression" which is usually used throughout the standard.  A template parameter is required to be a constant expression, instead of a compile-time constant.  However `std::ratio` specifically says "compile-time constant", which seems to make it technically more restrictive than a regular template parameter.  In practice, I doubt it makes any difference though.

Comment: @EricPostpischil It has to be evaluated at compile-time, because its used as template parameter. The compiler will generate a template class, and use that value at compile time to figure out all dependent types and values, such as `::num`.

Comment: @Paul: This is likely but is not deducible from the C++ standard due to the “as if” rule. It is widely known that the standard only specifies “observable” effects, not implementation details.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you use `constexpr` for Value too? I think it will ask the compiler to evaluate it,

```
constexpr int Value = 123 * 2 + GetOffset();
```

if the function GetOffset() is simple and meet the requirements of `constexpr`.

The requirements are

1. the function must have a non-void return type.
2. the function body cannot declare variables or define new types.
3. the body may contain only declarations, null statements and a single return
   statement.

Since `Getoffset()` returns `int`, it meets the first one.

Comment: Applied to a variable, `constexpr` is the same as `const`. The only difference is that it places more constraints on the type and initialiser.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, I think you can use `constexpr` in array definitions and a plan `const` can not? That's the difference for them which implies that `constexpr` should be initialized by the compiler?

Comment: You can use `const` variables as constant expressions (including array sizes). A `constexpr` variable is actually specified by "A `constexpr` specifier used in an object declaration declares the object as `const`", followed by some restrictions.

Comment: (That comment only applies to C++; I've just noticed that the question was mistagged "C", despite being about a language feature that doesn't exist in that language).

Comment: @user1131467: Yes, it would give a compile-time check that the initialiser is indeed a constant expression. But, in this case, we already know that it is.

Answer (score 3):

You can't ensure the compiler does this. You generally need to enable optimization, including some level of function inlining. What these options are depend on your compiler and its version.

You can check the generated assembly to see if it contains a call to `GetOffset` or just uses a constant determined by the compiler.

Comment: This may not work.  GetOffSet could be inlined without compiler computing the result directly, resulting in no call to GetOffSet, but still not quite the optimization the OP is looking for.  More extensive search of the assembly may be required.  Though this is being really picky.

Comment: How can I check assembly in VS?

Comment: @rubenvb: Could you please elaborate more? By looking at assembly language how someone will make sure that `GetOffset` has been already evaluated?

Comment: @user2729562 Run your program in debug mode, then pause it, Right-click > Go To Disassembly.

Comment: @ChrisCM nitpicker `;-)`

Comment: In debug mode optimizations will be turned off.

Comment: You can still debug with optimizations, you just have to modify the debug target to include optimizations.  Or better, create your own target that is "optimized debug" because you are correct, in that certain variables or inlined functions get hidden from the debugger by optimizations.  But the call stack is still accurate, and assembler still available.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/606cbtzs.aspx

Answer (score 3):

what if you declare 'Value' as constexpr too? Actually you can probalby never be sure if something is evaluated at compilation time, however in this case there is no reason why it could not be evaluated.

Answer (score 2):

You can't be absolutely sure; the compiler is only required to generate code with the specified behaviour, and calculating it at compile- or run-time would not change the behaviour.

However, the compiler is required to be *able* to evaluate this at compile time, since it can be used where only compile-time constants are allowed such as array sizes and template arguments; so there's no reason why a sane compiler shouldn't perform that obvious optimisation. If the compiler doesn't (at least with optimisations enabled), throw it away and find a better one.

You can check the assembly produced by the compiler to see whether it calculates the value; but this in itself doesn't guarantee that future builds will do the same.

Comment: That's why I need to check it.

Comment: @user2729562: As I said, check the assembly. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Are there any compiler-specific hacks to do it?

Comment: @user2729562: I don't know, but I doubt it. A decent compiler will do the optimisation anyway, so there's no need for a way to check; a rubbish compiler is unlikely to offer any way to test its rubbishness.

Comment: Ok, I see where you're going now.  `constexpr` will require the initializer to be a constant expression, or it will fail to compile.  This is better than `const` which has no such requirement.  See my answer.  Whether or not the compiler actually evaluates constant expressions during translation is unspecified, but it would be an extremely unusual compiler that could decide if an expression is constant (as required), but didn't actually evaluate it.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that I have not used C++ in over half a decade now, the chances of the suggestion being way of the mark are quite high, but what about using inline for the function.

If the function returns a certain predefined value, available at the compile time, then the compiler should be able to make use of that value.

Comment: I do. But how to make sure the compiler does its job properly?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate source file with the expression. Evaluate `printf("#define MyExpression %d.\n", expression);`. When building your project, compile this source file for the native system and execute it. Include the resulting output as a header in your regular sources.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to confirm that the initializer is a constant expression than you can use the `constexpr` specifier:

```
constexpr int Value = 123 * 2 + GetOffset();
```

It will fail to compile if it isn't a constant expression.

It is theoretically unspecified whether a constexpr variable `Value` is actually calculated during translation - but in practice you can be sure it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just assert it: `static_assert(Value == 123 * 2 + GetOffset(), "constexpr");`
Doesn't get any simpler than that.